# Calculate the sum of a sum in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function Y(k) of matrices Bi, which I calculate like this:

```
function Y = specm(A,k)
% A is a 3-D array, and k is a number from 1 to p( p is the number of matrices in A)
B = eye(size(A,2));
p = size(A,3);
if k > 0;
  B = B' * A(:,:,k);
end
for l = 1:(p-k);
  B = B + A(:,:,l)' * A(:,:,k+l);
end
if k > 0;
  Y = 2*B;
end
end
```

The issue is that I would like to have the sum of Y for all k from 1 to p. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with `sum of Y for all k from 1 to p`? Do you refer to `rows` or `columns` of `Y`? The only loop in your code is from 1 to `p-k`; moreover, at the end of your script, you have just one `Y`. Anyway, to sum all the element of a matrix `M` use: `sum(sum(M))`. Please, clarify your question.

Comment: I think what OP means in instead of calling `specm` for each value of `k` and then getting `Y`, he would like to calculate sum of all `Y`s for `k=1:p`. Am I right @Maanan?

Comment: Yes you are right, @Parag. And I would like the function to have only one input argument, specm(A), instead of specm(A,k).